# Spliting message before sending UDP netty

Tags: java, netty

I'm having a problem related to the sending of a byte array through netty, the equipment that receives the command (byte array) apparently allows only 1024 bytes at time, and the length of the byte array is 1301. So i try to split this byte array, and tried to send them separatedly, sending 1024 first and them 277 after.

But still dosen't work, i was figuring out if i have to make some changes on my pipeline, because netty allow us to limit the message received, into multiple messages. But i dont know how i would do that, when it comes to send the message. I try to read the doc, but cant find anything about that topic.

````
public class EquipProtocol extends BaseProtocol {

    @Override
    public void initTrackerServers(List<TrackerServer> serverList) {
        serverList.add(new TrackerServer(new ServerBootstrap()) {
            @Override
            protected void addSpecificHandlers(ChannelPipeline pipeline) {
                pipeline.addLast("objectDecoder", new EquipProtocolDecoder(EquipProtocol.this));
            }
        });
        serverList.add(new TrackerServer(new ConnectionlessBootstrap()) {
            @Override
            protected void addSpecificHandlers(ChannelPipeline pipeline) {
                pipeline.addLast("objectDecoder", new EquipProtocolDecoder(EquipProtocol.this));
            }
        });
    }

}```
````

Comment: Many details are missing here. What does it mean "[send them separatedly] still dosen't work"? "Netty allow us to limit the message received, into multiple messages" - how exactly?

Comment: Processing of outbound messages can be done in so called encoders, see classes io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToByteEncoder, MessageToMessageEncoder. Maybe even one of their inheritors from standard netty library can help you.